# Is there a way to show notifications while screen sharing on Zoom on OSX?

Tags: macos, screen-sharing, zoom-meeting

There's a lot of resources to make sure that notifications don't pop up - Such as turning Do Not Disturb on and using third party apps. But I want to SHOW the notifications while I'm screen sharing on Zoom.

[In this case the notification pops up and I can see it on the host side on the Top Right Corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlkU7.jpg)

But nothing shows up on the client side

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you run fullscreen? I don't use the free Screen Sharing, but I do use Apple Remote Desktop [which is the same technology]. No issues with notifications on local or remote machine.

Comment: I should have clarified this was when I was attempting to screen share using zoom

Answer (score 5):

The option is easy to overlook, but here's what I found.

#### macOS 13 (Ventura) or newer

Navigate to **System Settings...**, found under "apple" menu in the left top corner of the screen, scroll to **Notifications**, and switch this box to enable:

> Allow notifications **when mirroring or sharing the display**

Example:
[image: macOS 13+ settings]

---

#### On macOS 12 (Monterey) or older

Navigate to **System Preferences**, found under "apple" menu in the left top corner of the screen, go to **Notifications & Focus**, and check this box:

> Allow Notifications: **When mirroring or sharing the display**.

Example:

[image: Screenshot of "Notifications & Focus"]

Comment: So even with this setting turned on, zoom hides the notifications